# How to perform action for all combinations of elements in lists?

Tags: kotlin

I have multiple lists, for the sake of simplicity, let's say 2:

```
val names = listOf("John", "Tom")
val days = listOf(1, 2, 3)
```

And I want to iterate over all the combinations of these possible values with a function `f: (String, Int): Unit`:

```
f("John", 1)
f("John", 2)
f("John", 3)
f("Tom", 1)
f("Tom", 2)
f("Tom", 3)
```

I'd like to find out the idiomatic way to do this in kotlin. Off the top of my head, I imagine that this can be done with a nested map. Something along the lines of:

```
a.map { itA -> 
  b.map { itB ->
    f(itA, itB)
  }
}
```

**EDIT**:
This doesn't seem to work for me though as it returns:

```
[() -> kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.Unit>, () -> kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.Unit>]
```

Comment: What exactly "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: Please - edit and correct your question! It works and what you are doing wrong here has NOTHING to do with combinations. By now you should have found that out... It's sad to stumble upon such questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `forEach` is the closest as it can get:

```
names.forEach {
    i -> days.forEach { j -> f(i, j)}
}
```

---

**Example:**

```
private fun f(i: String, j: Int) = println("$i,$j")
```

Result:

```
John,1
John,2
John,3
Tom,1
Tom,2
Tom,3
```

Comment: Which one is more idiomatic, the `forEach` solution or the nested `for` loops, keeping in mind that the number of lists could be up to 10?

Comment: @breezymri I would say those are equal

Answer (score 12):

The name of the output you're looking for is a [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

If you don't need all of the combinations up front, and you're just searching for one or more, you could make it a lazily generated sequence:

```
private fun <A, B> lazyCartesianProduct(
    listA: Iterable<A>,
    listB: Iterable<B>
): Sequence<Pair<A, B>> =
    sequence {
        listA.forEach { a ->
            listB.forEach { b ->
                yield(a to b)
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you can map, filter etc only what you need:

```
val names = listOf("John", "Tom")
val days = listOf(1, 2, 3)

lazyCartesianProduct(names, days)
    .map { it.toSomethingElse() }
    .find { it.isWhatImLookingFor() }
```

Answer (score 5):

What's wrong with a regular `for` loop?

```
for (name in names) for (day in days) f(name, day)
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you actually need the result from `f` here's what you can do:

```
fun <T1, T2, R> combine(
        first: Iterable<T1>,
        second: Iterable<T2>,
        combiner: (T1, T2) -> R
): List<R> = first.flatMap { firstItem -> second.map { secondItem -> combiner(firstItem, secondItem) } }

@Test fun test() {
    val names = listOf("John", "Tom")
    val days = listOf(1, 2, 3)

    val result = combine(days, names, { day, name -> "${day}. ${name}" })

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    kotlin.test.assert(result) {
        shouldBe(listOf(
                "1. John",
                "1. Tom",
                "2. John",
                "2. Tom",
                "3. John",
                "3. Tom"
        ))
    }
}
```

Note: it also works with `println`, in that case `R` is `Unit`.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate different combinations via flat mapping.

```
val names = listOf("John", "Tom")
val days = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val isSht = listOf(true, false)

val combz =
     names.flatMap { name ->
        days.flatMap { day ->
            isSht.map { isSht -> "${day} ${isSht}" }
        }.map { daySht -> "${daySht} ${name}" }
    }.toList()
```